# Android app is crashing each time I run it

Tags: java, android

I started BLE113 and Android programming. I followed the guidelines from this website:

http://www.software7.com/blog/creating-a-beacon-app-for-android-in-less-than-10-minutes-from-scratch/

Everything was working great when I followed the tutorial. Then I started to play with the code. Instead of reading the distance and the UUID on the Android terminal, I decided to read it on the app. The app is being shutdown each time I run it and getting the following message:
“unfortunately, *app name* has stopped”.
I really don’t understand why is that.
Here is the code when my app crashes:

```
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
    for (Beacon oneBeacon: beacons) {
       // Log.d(Tag, "distance:"+oneBeacon.getDistance() + "id:" +oneBeacon.getId1()+ "/" + oneBeacon.getId2()+"/" + oneBeacon.getId3());

        TextView distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distanceText);
        distance.setText(""+oneBeacon.getDistance());

    }
}
```

Here is when it doesn’t crash:

```
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
    for (Beacon oneBeacon: beacons) {
       Log.d(Tag, "distance:"+oneBeacon.getDistance() + "id:" +oneBeacon.getId1()+ "/" + oneBeacon.getId2()+"/" + oneBeacon.getId3());

        //TextView distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distanceText);
        //distance.setText(""+oneBeacon.getDistance());

    }
}
```

Full code is published here:

https://github.com/Boniface316/androidProjects#androidprojects

I started Android programming 4 weeks ago and still learning, I really don’t know why I am getting this message. Any suggestions or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, click on "Android Monitor", on the footer of the IDE, and see where the code is crashing. Post this log to help possible answers.

Comment: Are you possibly trying to call findViewById on something other than the Id? If that is the case than you will need to use the actual Id or getIdentifier to work around the issue.

Comment: I have no idea how to use the android monitor to  find where the code is crashing :(, Could you guide me through?

Comment: Alex, this is the only id that I am trying to reach. There are no other ID.

Comment: The error you're running into is trying to update the UI (e.g. a TextView) from a non-UI thread (which is what you end up with on that callback). If you use a runOnUiThread and try to do that, it will work.

Comment: @SJoshi, I will give it a try. with runOnUiThread.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use the debugging tools to get errors using eclipse or Android Studio. That is the best way to find the issue

As far as I can see you should remove the initialization of `distance` out this method.

Declare it as a field:

```
private TextView distance;
```

intialize it in `onCreate()`

```
distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distanceText);
```

Then

```
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
    for (Beacon oneBeacon: beacons) {
       // Log.d(Tag, "distance:"+oneBeacon.getDistance() + "id:" +oneBeacon.getId1()+ "/" + oneBeacon.getId2()+"/" + oneBeacon.getId3());
        distance.setText(distance.getText() +  " | "+oneBeacon.getDistance());
    }
}
```

Also change the loop code to :

```
distance.setText(distance.getText() +  " | "+oneBeacon.getDistance());
```

Otherwise you would overwrite it

Comment: I tried this method and still no luck. I am not understanding why its doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @blackknight316 what is the error you are getting now

Comment: I am getting the following message and the app is closed:

"Unfortunately, AltBeacon has stopped."

Comment: @blackknight316 you need to get the error log from log cat

Comment: @blackknight316 http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-android-s-log-class-api-to-debug-android-application-code.html

Comment: I will go through link you sent me. Here is the log from my app, I dont know how to interpret.

https://github.com/Boniface316/androidProjects/tree/master/AltBeacon/Log

Comment: can we setup another chat?

Comment: @blackknight316 sure

Comment: Sorry @meda, I was out of town. Could you let me know the best time time for you this week?

Comment: Cool, so how can I start the chatting thingy?

Comment: I checked and I have no idea how to initiate it

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100534/discussion-between-meda-and-blackknight316

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the beacon thing... but as I guess,

that didRangeBeaconsInRegion method is being called from another thread, which is not main UI thread.

In android, UI related works are needed to be done in main thread and network related works have to be done in a separate thread.

I guess that beacon thing uses the network connection in another thread and calls this method in its own network thread.

Try using handler to send message to main thread for UI update.